# Слово this в аргументе конструктора

Tags: java

Встретил такой код

```
public EWrapperImpl() {
    readerSignal = new EJavaSignal();
    clientSocket = new EClientSocket(this, readerSignal);
}
```

При создании экземпляра `clientSocket` передаем в конструктор `this`.

Что это? Экземпляр обьета? Какого обьекта ... `EWrapperImpl`? Или `EClientSocket`?

Answer (score 6):

Ключевое слово `this` всегда является ссылкой на экземпляр класса в котором оно используется. В вашем случае это `EWrapperImpl`

Надо заметить, что это правило действует и для вложенных классов. Например:

```
public class Outher {

    public Outher() {
        //в этом месте this - это ссылка на класс Outher
    }

    class Inner {

        public Inner() {
            //в этом месте this - это ссылка на класс Inner

            //а чтобы во внутреннем классе получить ссылку на внешний класс
            //надо делать так ИмяВнешнегоКласса.this, т.е так:
            //Outher.this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`this` – это ссылка на текущий объект – объект, чей метод или конструктор вызывается. Насколько я понимаю, Ваша полная конструкция выглядит [так](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/client_wrapper.html#gsc.tab=0):

```
public class EWrapperImpl implements EWrapper {
    private EReaderSignal readerSignal;
    private EClientSocket clientSocket;
    protected int currentOrderId = -1;

    public EWrapperImpl() {
        readerSignal = new EJavaSignal();
        clientSocket = new EClientSocket(this, readerSignal);
    }
}
```

Здесь `this` – это ссылка на экземпляр класса `EWrapperImpl`.

Comment: Спасибо. Видимо вы знаете этот API раз написали  readerSignal = new EJavaSignal();

Comment: Пожалуйста. Нет, не знаком я с этим.